# Autonomous RC Car Competitions in germany

Tags: autonomous-car, self-driving

Together with a friend of mine and my professor, we were able to build a team and come up with our own self driving rc car.

Due to time we didn’t manage to apply for Carolo-Cup, which is a very good competition where teams from all over the country participate with their own self driving cars.

Does anyone know if there is another autonomous driving rc Car competition in Germany that would take place in early phase of 2020 ?

Comment: The “SEAT Autonomous Driving Challenge” isn't located in Germany but in Spain. Similar to the Carolo cup, RC driven cars have to master a track.

Answer (score 2):

You can find more info about many kinds competitions [here](https://diyrobocars.com/autonomous-racing-leaguescompetitions/)